# Rails self referencing has_one with dynamic condition on nested model - Admin Employee Client role based

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations, has-one

I have a unique user model with 3 roles :admin, :employee, :client (devise + pundit)

Admin creates Employees,
Employee belongs_to PrimaryBusiness (the company it's working for)
Employee creates Businesses with Clients (it's portfolio of companies and clients)

So, 
Business contains a user_id which is the Employee id

**Since Client belongs to a Business and Business contains the Employee, how can I get the Employee(User) with a has_one association ?**

Basically, I would like to have this method inside a User has_one :creator, which I guess makes sense :

```
# User.rb
get_creator
  User.find(current_user.primary_business.user_id)
end
```

More generally, is this the proper way to deal with the hierarchy
Admin(User) > Employees(User) > Businesses > Clients(User) ?
I put Business before Clients in the hierarchy because Client can leave the business, but Business remains.

```
#User.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :businesses
belongs_to :primary_business, class_name: "Business", foreign_key: "business_id"
end

#Business.rb
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user #here is the Employee
has_many :clients, class_name: "User", foreign_key: 'business_id' #here are 
the clients 
end
```

The closest I get so far is:

```
# User.rb
has_one :creator, ->(user) {where id:  user.primary_business.user_id }, class_name: self, foreign_key: "id"
```

But since I self referencing User, this result to a where user.id = 1 AND user.id = 2, then return nil
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it appears to be the correct way of going about that chain of associations.

The order can be a bit tricky:

> Admins -> Businesses -> Employees -> Businesses -> Clients

Edit: To add the has_one association on the User model for creator we can do this:

```
has_one :creator, through: :primary_business, source: :user
```

I would also change the 'clients' association to 'users' since it will contain Employees and Clients. My personal preference would also be to change the 'primary_business' association to 'business' for simplicity, but that is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the hint on primary_key, I didn't think of it. However, I do not get why you added the Businesses model between Admin and Employees. In my original example, admin only have many businesses through employees (even if theorically it can create business). and its primary_business is assigned by default. If I had to draw it, Businesses and Employees would be at the same parallel level, no ?

Comment: I made that connection because of the method you have above:

get_creator
  User.find(current_user.primary_business.user_id)
end

You asked how to get Employee with a has_one association, and since you would not want an Employee to just have one Client, I assume you mean that an Employee has one Admin. The method goes through primary_business to get a user, which is the Admin. Because of this I made the connection that an Admin has many Businesses.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the code required for the creator association. Please let me know how it works for you :-)

Comment: Sounds obvious now... And it works great, thanks mate!

Comment: Absolutely! Please select it as the answer if you feel it answered your question and helped. That way people don't navigate here thinking it is an unanswered question. Thanks!